# get false instead of empty array with checkbox

Tags: react-hook-form, zod

I create zod schema with array:

```
category: array(z.enum(['a', 'b']))
```

and I want to toggle the values checkbox:

```
<>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="a" {...register('category')} />a
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="b" {...register('category')} />b
  </label>
</>
```

it toggles it nicely, but when no checkbox is selected, I get `false` instead of an empty array. Is there any out-of-box solution in the react-hook-form register function or shell I need to implement?

Comment: add whole code here .So people can easily help you.

Comment: [useForm - register](https://www.react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register/) - on the documentation they use a empty array for a default value.